# excel index match do not ignore 0's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a function `=INDEX(Database!E$5:E$50,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Database!E$5:E$50<>0),0),0))` 
that searches a column, finds the first number and returns it. Right now it is ignoring cells in the column that have a value =0.

So, basically what's happening is that the function returns `22` as the first result instead  of `0.00`. 
[image]

I want it to ignore blank cells, but not cells with a value = 0 in them.

It's most likely a minor adjustment but I'm having a little difficulty.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=INDEX(Database!E$5:E$50,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Database!E$5:E$50<>""),0),0))
```

seems to work to me...
Substituting the `0` in your comparison with `""`.

Comment: Perfect. I Knew it was small.